# React replace App component State Data with JSON

Tags: json, reactjs, react-props

I am attempting to load Json data In react component. I have two component `ProjectCardContainer` and `ProjectDetailPage` in which when I click on `<h6>` link I want `App` state data to be displayed as text `ProjectDetailPage`. Then I come to know that React State are local they can't be passed to another component.Hence I created Json as `CardData` But now the problem is how can I render `CardData` by replacing or modifying `App` and render them in `ProjectDetailPage` as text ?

Thanks.

[Code Gist](https://gist.github.com/amarg26/a696da147f0519a23ed9a01fbc956f9b)

CardData.tsx

```
const CardData = {
  "cards": [
    {
      "projectID": "00001",
      "projectName": "One tent system",
      "profileProjectImage": "https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/cdn.br.catarse/uploads/project/uploaded_image/72644/project_thumb_large_capinha.jpg",
      "projectBy": "Crua Outdoors",
      "projectDescrition": "Lightweight Hiking Tent + Insulated Cocoon + Air-Framed Living Space: Use individually or together for the ultimate outdoors experience",
      "projectLocation": " New York, NY"
    },
    {
      "projectID": "00002",
      "projectName": "Two tent system",
      "profileProjectImage": "https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/cdn.br.catarse/uploads/project/uploaded_image/72644/project_thumb_large_capinha.jpg",
      "projectBy": "Crua Outdoors",
      "projectDescrition": "Lightweight Hiking Tent + Insulated Cocoon + Air-Framed Living Space: Use individually or together for the ultimate outdoors experience",
      "projectLocation": " New York, NY"
    },
    {
      "projectID": "00003",
      "projectName": "Three tent system",
      "profileProjectImage": "https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/cdn.br.catarse/uploads/project/uploaded_image/72644/project_thumb_large_capinha.jpg",
      "projectBy": "Crua Outdoors",
      "projectDescrition": "Lightweight Hiking Tent + Insulated Cocoon + Air-Framed Living Space: Use individually or together for the ultimate outdoors experience",
      "projectLocation": " New York, NY"
    }
  ]
}
export default CardData;
```

Comment: You can add redux to your application and create reducer for your card data. This can be subscribed by the components where yiu want to show them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you have the `App` component when you already have the `ProjectCardContainer` component. Just import the data you exporting in the snippet you shared above, and set that as the state. (Make sure your import path is correct.)

```
import CardData from './CardData'

class ProjectCardContainer extends React.Component {
  state = CardData;
  render() {
    return <CardList cards={this.state.cards} />;
  }
}
```